# Is it fine to provide message exchange in WAN by rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to build a cluster in Internet. It likely deploy openstack neutron with its agents not in same idc, but can be in anywhere and connect by WAN. Those agents also need to connect server, and server also need to push some data to agent. I'm doubt rabbitmq can be used in WAN. Since we should consider the cluster security and network failure issues. I also investigate the grpc. But seems grpc do not support amqp, so it is not convenient to make a remote procedure call to some same role agents.

Did someone use rabbitmq in WAN? Or should I chose another middle to provide message exchange service? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function sendOrder()
{

    foreach ($$_REQUEST->div['producte'] as $producte) {
    $avg+= $producte['qty'] ;
        if($producte['qty']>0)
        {
    $ord_item=new order_items(
    ['id'=>$producte->id,
     'qty'=>$producte['qty']
    ]
    );
    $ord_item->save();
        }
    }
    $order=new orders(['qty'=>$avg]);
    $order->save();
    return $this->render('catalog',['data'=>$order]);


}
```